# how to prove 2 sql statements are equivalent

Tags: sql, theory, performance

I set out to rewrite a complex SQL statement with joins and sub-statements and obtained a more simple looking statement. I tested it by running both on the same data set and getting the same result set. In general, how can I (conceptually) prove that the 2 statements are the same in any given data set?

Comment: Formally? By using relational algebra: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra

Comment: Are you worried about performance, or only data correctness? Different queries may be processed differently by the database engine. Even though they may be formally equivalent, they may practically be very different. Something like Oracle's explain plan might be helpful to see what the database is *actually* doing with your sql. If it's doing the same thing with both, you win ;-D

Comment: Formal proof may be too much for me. I just want to make sure that they are equivalent and correct without having to run them on all data sets.

Comment: You could maybe plug the two queries into a parser (http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) to get their equivalent parse trees.  If you normalized the two trees, you may be able to prove they are equivalent that way.

Comment: @Martin post a question here with both queries, add a bounty - profit!

Comment: Formal proof might not be enough. There are a lot of edge cases and odd corners in SQL implementations. Microsoft wrote a program to generate millions of random, syntactically correct SQL statements. Then they ran them against multiple dbms implementations and compared the results. About 15% of the statements produced different output (or errors) on at least one comparison system. The program was called RAGS, for "Random Generation of SQL".

Comment: @Mchl Whoa, who new that that existed, its like SQL but...algebraic I will definitely study that...

Comment: @Triztian: Definitely guys at IBM knew this when they drafted first specs of SQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest studying relational algebra (as pointed out by Mchl). It is the most essential concept you need if you want to get serious about optimizing queries and designing databases properly.

However I will suggest an ugly brute force approach that helps you to ensure correct results if you have sufficient data to test with: create views of both versions (for making the comparisons easier to manage) and compare the results. I mean something like

```
create view original as select xxx yyy zzz;
create view new as select xxx yyy zzz;
-- If the amount differs something is quite obviously very wrong
select count(*) from original;
select count(*) from new;
-- What is missing from the new one?
select *
from original o
where not exists (
 select * 
 from new n
 where o.col1=n.col2 and o.col2=n.col2 --and so on
);
-- Did something extra appear?
select *
from new o
where not exists (
 select *
 from old n
 where o.col1=n.col2 and o.col2=n.col2 --and so on
)
```

Also as pointed out by others in comments you might feed both the queries to the optimizers of the product you are working with. Most of the time you get something that can be parsed with humans, complete drawings of the execution paths with the subqueries' impact on the performance etc. It is most often done with something like

```
explain plan for 
select * 
from ...
where ...
etc
```

Comment: Same output does not necessitate equivalence of queries, but different output proves that the queries are inequivalent.